# How to scroll top of Toggle Slider Content to center of viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have those toggle slider on my website. Please view here:

http://nextree.ch/module/

To recreate the issue, please click on "Kunden" then scroll down and click on "Produkte". Now you will notice that you are thrown into the middle of something very, very long. That is irritating the visitor of the website. What I would like to achieve is, to have the top of the content always at a certain place of the viewport. Like maybe 200px offset from top or to the center of the viewport. Understand?

This is the current code to make the toggle slider work:

```
$("p.trigger, h3.trigger").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var hasActive = $this.hasClass('active');

    $("p.trigger, h3.trigger").removeClass("active");
    $('.toggle_container').not($this.next()).slideUp();
    if (!hasActive) {
        $this.addClass("active");
    }
    $this.next().slideToggle(500);
    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start the second animation after the first finished. To achieve this, use the complete callback of [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

```
$("p.trigger, h3.trigger").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var hasActive = $this.hasClass('active');

    $("p.trigger, h3.trigger").removeClass("active");
    $('.toggle_container').not($this.next()).slideUp(500, function() {
        if (!hasActive) {
            $this.addClass("active");
        }
        $this.next().slideToggle(500);
    });

    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `scrollIntoView` function. You could call it on the title of the clicked element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView